# Does re-authenticating to apps on an unlocked phone really make an app more secure?

Tags: authentication, mobile

Several apps on my iPhone X including LastPass, and iCloud passwords prompt me for my Face ID before allowing me to use them. I guess the idea is that someone could accidentally take my unlocked phone and access my personal information.

How likely is this in reality given that the phone has a short inactivity timer? Are there any examples of someone being mugged while using their phone, and the mugger kept it unlocked long enough to commit further fraud, etc?

Comment: The pattern is the same for Android, too, and not limited to iPhone or FaceID, so I generalised the question.

Comment: Plenty of "friends" would like access to many of their "friends" passwords. No mugging necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is emphatically "yes". Theft of phones, while someone is using them, is well-documented. Often thieves use bikes or mopeds.

Here are my top Google hits for the phrase "snatching phone" (results are geo-located to UK sources). I'm not sure if it is an official phrase.

- https://www.met.police.uk/cp/crime-prevention/personal-robbery/protect-your-mobile-phone-against-criminals-on-bikes-and-mopeds/
- https://www.cnet.com/g00/news/when-your-phone-gets-snatched-a-survival-guide/?i10c.ua=1&i10c.encReferrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8%3d&i10c.dv=17
- https://www.ucl.ac.uk/students/news/2019/jul/phone-snatching-how-avoid-it
- https://www.independent.co.uk/student/student-life/it-could-happen-to-you-how-to-protect-yourself-from-phone-snatchers-9166322.html

Comment: And even more common: "Aren't these baby pictures sooo cute?" *hands over unlocked phone to friend that should not be trusted*

Comment: @Anders *Nice! Let me take a picture of your "baby" with my phone*. Proceeds to screenshot your credentials.